# How to call all the workers in the gunicorn/uvicorn application servers

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, uwsgi, uvicorn

There is some heavy file (in GBs) workers are loading up into the memory, for search, its okay if any worker picks up, but while *inserting* the new data one worker picking up the request makes the other workers to be in the inconsistent state.

As connectivity to database is not possible, as the file is loading from the **disk**. Looking for some approach, where I can call all the workers while *inserting* to reduce the inconsistency.

If gunicorn/uvicorn are not built on these lines, what are the other alternative WSGI servers can be used.

Comment: "but while inserting the new data one worker picking up the request makes the other workers to be in the inconsistent state." can you be more precise of this inconsistent state ?
Also having some code to look at would be nice, because depending of the libs you use to load you files, your api may or may not use it's memory to load you files. Also are you using tasks queu like celery ?

Comment: Lets say, 

A gunicorn server is listening 8080 port with 2 Flask Workers spawned. Each Flask Worker reads some heavy binary file (Vector data / Index file, for example 1M vectors data) while spawning up, and it has 2 roles.

1) Check if there are any nearby vectorsto the incoming request data ornot.
2) Insert into the binary file.

After the workers spawned up, (1) is okay, whichever worker processes it, gives the same result. But for (2) as gunicorn worker directs to one worker, one worker updates its binary file loaded into the memory and making it up-to-date. So, the inconsistency.